# <C language> switch-case : incorrect boolean results

Tags: c

here is the code lines.
programming language : C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool output(int month,int day)
{
switch(month){
case 1 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 2 :
if(day<=29) return true;
break;
case 3 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 4 :
if(day<=30) return true;
break;
case 5 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 6 :
if(day<=30) return true;
break;
case 7 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 8 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 9 :
if(day<=30) return true;
break;
case 10 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
case 11 :
if(day<=30) return true;
break;
case 12 :
if(day<=31) return true;
break;
default : 
return false;
}
}

int main()
{
int month, day;
scanf("%d %d",&month,&day);
if(output(month,day))
{
printf("OK! \n");
}
else
{
printf("BAD! \n");
}
printf("%d %d \n",month,day);
return 0;
}
```

the code result is that,
when input data is 2(month) 30(day) in main function, i always get “OK! 2 30” as result. if data of month and day are 2 and 30, the result should be BAD!, because it returns false value of output function case 2.

please help me which part in my code is incorrect.thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply debug into the code step by step to isolate the issue?

Comment: Technically it should not compile without a warning because not all paths of `output` return a value. When the month is 2 you do your tests there. But think about what happens when the day value is 30. Where will the code lead to? The answer explains ...

Comment: The compiler should show you some warning like "Reaching end of non-void function without returning a value". You should increase warning level of your compiler. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also wish to consider taking advantage of the fall through behavior of the switch statement, and returning the result of the boolean expressions directly.

```
bool output(int month,int day) {
    switch (month) {
        case 2:
        return day <= 29;

        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
        return day <= 30; 

        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12 :
        return day <= 31;

        default : 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `return` after the `switch` statement, so, whenever any of the cases executes a `break`, the function ends without returning a value. When the `main` routine attempts to use the value of the function, the behavior is undefined.

Add `return false;` at the end of the function.

Alternately, you could change all the cases to return values and never break, as with:

```
case 1: return day <= 31;
case 2: return day <= 28;
case 3: return day <= 31;
…
```

Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. Start with `-Wmost` with Clang, `-Wall` with GCC, and `/W3` with MSVC.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i should pay attention to compiler warning.